# Prime and semiprime ideals of $A=T_3(D)$, the ring of $3\times 3$ upper triangular matrices over $D$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $D$ be a division ring. Could anyone tell me which are the prime and semiprime ideals of $A=T_{3}(D)$, where $A=T_{3}(D)$ the ring of $3\times 3$ upper triangular matrices with coefficients in $D$?

Answer (score 3):

1. Since $A$ is left (and right) Artinian, the prime ideals are the maximal ideals.
2. The set $J$ of strictly upper triangular matrices is nilpotent, and hence it is contained in all prime ideals.
3. $A/J\cong D\times D\times D$ is semisimple, showing that $J$ is the Jacobson radical of $A$. Hence the maximal ideals of $A$ correspond to those of $A/J$.
4. These maximal ideals are easy to catalogue: $I_1\lhd A$ corresponding to the matrices zero on the $1,1$ position, $I_2$ the set of matrices zero on the $2,2$ position, and $I_3$ the matrices zero on the $3,3$ position. This is a complete list of the prime ideals.
5. A complete list of semiprime ideals is given by all possible intersections of the prime ideals, namely: $I_1,\ \ I_2,\ \ I_3,\ \  I_1\cap I_2,\ \ I_1\cap I_3,\ \ I_2\cap I_3,\ \ I_1\cap I_2\cap I_3=J$.